# Scala REPL Crash

Tags: command-line, java, crash, scala

I've tried Scala on two computers. It works fine on a Windows Professional 64-Bit OS, but the REPL and `scalac` crash nastily on Windows Professional 32-Bit when running directly from the command line.

I've tried both the 2.9 and 2.10 releases, and they both return the following error:

```
C:\>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-M6 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x : Int = 1

Failed to initialize the REPL due to an unexpected error.
This is a bug, please, report it along with the error diagnostics printed below.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown character property name {r} near index 5
^C:\Program Files\Java\includes\.*.jar$
```

Followed by about 100 lines of related errors grouped under that first one. I'm not sure what to make of it. Perhaps more interestingly, it seems to work fine when I run it from Netbeans.

I have the latest version of the JDK installed (7u5), if that makes a difference.

Comment: _This is a bug, please, report it along_

Comment: Did so. Looks like nobody has an answer. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: you can add your own answer, complete with links to the bug report :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody seems to have an answer to this one, and @Sathya suggested that I report it as a bug. You can find the [report link here](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6194) if you're interested. I'd be curious to know if anybody else can reproduce this.